# Is this "Last Boy Scout" henchman portrayed by Dan Castellaneta?

Tags: character, the-last-boy-scout

The 1991 film "[**The Last Boy Scout**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Boy_Scout)" stars Bruce Willis as a burned-out private detective and Damon Wayans as a former football player. While investigating the death of the latter's girlfriend, the two find themselves accosted by two of the main villain's henchmen - a well-dressed gentleman and a large thug named Jake. Both henchmen

> promptly meet their deaths when Jake shoots the trunk of the car containing an explosive.

The one in the suit appears to be portrayed by [Dan Castellaneta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Castellaneta), who would rise to fame later that same year for his voice work on "[The Simpsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons)" (primarily as Homer Simpson). However, when I attempted to confirm it was Castellaneta, I was unable to find his name in the credits. Neither IMDb nor Wikipedia list him as being in "The Last Boy Scout". I don't think the character is even listed, given that it's such a small part. Here's a screenshot of the character in question:

[image]

I may be completely wrong and it's not Castellaneta at all, but it certainly looks a lot like him, especially when compared to 1990/1991 photos of him.

**Can someone confirm whether or not the character above is indeed played by Dan Castellaneta of 'The Simpsons' fame?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like the same actor to me.

Here's Dan Castellaneta's [imdb](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0144657/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), which doesn't list The Last Boy Scout as one of his movies, as you state in your question.

The actor in the screen shot looks to be [Jack Kehler](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0444940/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t40), listed as Scrabble Man on IMDB.  He's listed with 165 credits on IMDB, he's kind of a forgettable every man that Hollywood uses.